# Laravel blade templating - order of markup is messed up

Tags: templates, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm currently working on the frontend for a project and right now I'm creating all the views. I have a template, which roughly looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-GB">

<head>
  <!-- TITLE -->
 <title>@yield('title')</title>
 /*Fonts, meta, css and script references go here too*/
</head>


<body id=@yield('body-id')>

 <!-- HEADER -->
  @section('header')
    <header id="sticky-header">
      /*Logo and some other stuff*/
      @include('navigation')
    </header>
@yield_section

<!--CONTENT-->
<div id="content">
  @yield('content')
</div>


<!--FOOTER-->
<footer id="footer" role="contentinfo">
  @yield('footer')
  /*Copyright stuff*/
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

And my view, which looks like this:

```
@layout('templates.main')

@section('title')
Graddle.se - Home
@endsection

@section('body-id')
"start-page"
@endsection

<header id="header">
 <div class="social-buttons-container">
  <ul class="social-buttons">
  <li>{{ HTML::image('img/facebook_logo.png', 'Facebook', array('class' => 'social-button')); }}</li>
  <li>{{ HTML::image('img/twitter_logo.png', 'Twitter', array('class' => 'social-button')); }}</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  @include('navigation')
</header>


@section('content')
The website content goes here! 
@endsection

@section('footer')
Footer stuff!
@endsection
```

Note that I will have two headers on this page. This is by design. So my problem is this:

I wanted to insert a  to wrap the whole body to do some css-stuff. I inserted the code into the template and it showed up, and everything got wrapped except the footer. Also, when I check the source-code in the browser and in the Chrome inspector it shows up in a wierd order:

If I check the chrome inspector the markup is ordered like this:

```
<head>
</head>

<body id="start-page">
/*content from the <head> goes here*/

/*Webpage content goes here, sticky-header from the template etc*/

<footer>
Footer stuff
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, if I do ctrl-U and check the source code, the markup shows up like this:

```
<header id="header">
/*inserted by the view*/
</header>

<html>
<head>
/*Header stuff here, as it should be*/
</head>

<body id="start-page">

/*All the content*/

<footer>
Footer content
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Page looks fine though and everything is where it's supposed to be visually. So my questions are:

- How do I insert a  to wrap the whole content
  in body? Like I said, I can't wrap the footer.
- Why is the order of the markup so messed up, and shows differently in
  the chrome inspector and in the source-code?

I realise it might be a little unclear (I deleted some stuff in between to make the example more clear to make it easier to understand), just ask me if it is!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### 1. How do I insert a to wrap the whole content in body? Like I said, I can't wrap the footer.

I don't quite understand what you meant by the footer not being wrapped. In the code you provided the `<footer>` tag resides inside `<body>` tag.

### 2. Why is the order of the markup so messed up?

It's because in your view file, you didn't wrap the `<header>` tag inside any sections. You should wrap it inside either `header` or `content` section, according to your visual needs:

```
@section('header')
    @parent <!-- keep what's in the inherited layout file -->

    <header id="header">
        <div class="social-buttons-container">
            <!-- ... -->
        </div>
        @include('navigation')
    </header>
@endsection
```

### 3. Shows differently in the chrome inspector and in the source-code?

The inspector is formatting and organizing the HTML beautifully so developers can worry less about messy source code. According to [Google](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements):

> The Elements panel is sometimes a better way to "view source" for a
>   page. Inside the Elements panel, the page's DOM will be nicely
>   formatted, easily showing you HTML elements, their ancestry and their
>   descendants. Too often, pages you visit will have minified or simply
>   ugly HTML which makes it hard to see how the page is structured. The
>   Elements panel is your solution for viewing the real underlying
>   structure of the page.